SDK.getWebContext() throws exception when published
We are creating ADO Extension which is based on ASP.NET Core 8, Vite & REACT. We are using azure-devops-extension-sdk v4.0.2. When we use our application in Dev mode everything works fine BUT when we publish it SDK.getWebContext() starts throwing exception. Please see details below:
Exception:

Code where exception is throwing:

Vite config:

Please let me know if further details are needed.
Thanks,
Mustafa
I have tried various workarounds by calling SDK.Init() and SDK.ready() with different combinations but still no hope. Please let me know either we can totally ignore SDK in VITE and keep it in original shape or fix by changing any other combination of Init() and ready()?

You might need to provide more details of your code instead of a snapshot of small part of the code.
